# ASP.NET Core 5 error "No migrations configuration type was found in the assembly"

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core

I'm getting an error when I want to migrate a table to the database. I created the model, Dbcontext and database as well.
Here's the error that I'm getting:

> No migrations configuration type was found in the assembly 'Break'. (In Visual Studio you can use the Enable-Migrations command from Package Manager Console to add a migrations configuration).

When I type the "Enable-Migrations" command, it gives me another error:

> No context type was found in the assembly 'Break'.

I also installed the required packages such as `EntityFramework.tools` etc.
Here's my solution explorer:

[image: solution explorer]

It's kinda annoying :(

Comment: The starup project'"Break" seems not your current project, and from the error message, seems you are using `entityframework` instead of `entityframework core` in an asp.net-core project. You may take a look at the [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mvc-app/adding-model?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio)

Answer (score 1):

I solved it. By just simply using the "EntityFrameworkCore\Add-Migration" command instead of "Add-Migration".
Idk why is that but it worked for me!